# Will Stainless Steel Screws with Galvanized Hinges Cause Corrosion? (Exterior Application, Near Ocean)

Tags: screws, steel, hinges, stainless, galvanic-corrosion

I have a set of galvanized hinges for a shed door. The shed is located 50 feet from the ocean. Very salty air.

The hinges didn't come with screws and I'm having a hard time finding suitable galvanized screws, though I can easily source stainless steel screws for them.

I understand that in general, mixing dissimilar metals can accelerate corrosion.

Will this cause a problem for me?

Comment: Could you not replace the hinges with stainless steel hinges (which are going to be better suited to close to ocean use)?

Answer (score 4):

The galvanized is going to corrode regardless of the unlikely galvanic affect. Galvanic corrosion is only possible with an electrolyte; So when there is a film of water such as dew. The stainless ( likely 316 or 304) is fairly resistant to corrosion in that environment so any current flow would be very small ( very little galvanic affect). Life of the hinges will depend on the thickness of the zinc layer. Monel and cupronickel would be the best materials but costly.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal conditions using stainless steel screws with galvanized hinges would not cause much corrosion but there would be a substantial increase in corrosion in a heavy salt spray or salt water area. Galvanized steel will also corrode fairly fast in a salt spray area as will aluminum. You should really think about getting some stainless steel hinges to go along with your screws. Many home stores close to the coast and marine stores will carry them.

Comment: You mention "salt spray". While 50 feet _might_ be close enough to actually get sprayed on a windy day, would this be applicable as well to just salty/humid air that isn't depositing direct spray? Asking because I really don't know...

Comment: There **will, indeed, be salt spray** at 50 feet. Or considerably further, for that matter.

Comment: Yes, even if you can't feel it in the air, when I leave the cottage after just a few days of being parked there in the driveway, my windshield is usually covered in a white salty residue

Answer (score 0):

It'll be a problem, but **good paint** could help quite a lot.

I might also consider using through-bolts with backing plates rather than wood screws, but that's just me.

Comment: Paint on hinges won't help much... All the moving and adjacent surfaces will liberate themselves of that almost immediately, and then the process continues.